# When I run ./gradlew, why does the last line always state "> Building 87% > :bootRun"?

Tags: jhipster

I'm on a mac running commands from the terminal.  When I run `./gradlew` on a newly generated app, the start up messages display as well as all the logging.  Then the last line of output is always `> Building 87% > :bootRun`.  Even when more logging displays, that's always the last line.

The newly generated app appears to run fine.  However, the "Building 87%" suggests that something isn't finished.

What does `> Building 87% > :bootRun` mean and is it an issue?

```
dking@dking-mbp ~/Projects/test/myapp (master)$ ./gradlew
Starting the Unit and Integration test
:generateMainMapperClasses
:bower
:processResources
:compileJava
:compileScala UP-TO-DATE
:classes
:findMainClass
:bootRun

        ██  ██    ██  ████████  ███████    ██████  ████████  ████████  ███████
        ██  ██    ██     ██     ██    ██  ██          ██     ██        ██    ██
        ██  ████████     ██     ███████    █████      ██     ██████    ███████
  ██    ██  ██    ██     ██     ██             ██     ██     ██        ██   ██
   ██████   ██    ██  ████████  ██        ██████      ██     ████████  ██    ██

:: JHipster   :: Running Spring Boot 1.3.0.RELEASE ::
:: http://jhipster.github.io ::

[INFO] com.test.myapp.admin.Application - Starting Application on dking-mbp.home with PID 31568 (/Users/dking/Projects/test/myapp/build/classes/main started by dking in /Users/dking/Projects/test/myapp)
[DEBUG] com.test.myapp.admin.Application - Running with Spring Boot v1.3.0.RELEASE, Spring v4.2.3.RELEASE
[INFO] com.test.myapp.admin.Application - The following profiles are active: dev
[DEBUG] com.test.myapp.admin.config.AsyncConfiguration - Creating Async Task Executor
[DEBUG] com.test.myapp.admin.config.MetricsConfiguration - Registering JVM gauges
[DEBUG] com.test.myapp.admin.config.MetricsConfiguration - Initializing Metrics JMX reporting
[INFO] com.test.myapp.admin.config.WebConfigurer - Web application configuration, using profiles: [dev]
[DEBUG] com.test.myapp.admin.config.WebConfigurer - Initializing Metrics registries
[DEBUG] com.test.myapp.admin.config.WebConfigurer - Registering Metrics Filter
[DEBUG] com.test.myapp.admin.config.WebConfigurer - Registering Metrics Servlet
[DEBUG] com.test.myapp.admin.config.WebConfigurer - Initialize H2 console
[INFO] com.test.myapp.admin.config.WebConfigurer - Web application fully configured
[DEBUG] com.test.myapp.admin.config.DatabaseConfiguration - Configuring Datasource
[DEBUG] com.test.myapp.admin.config.DatabaseConfiguration - Configuring Liquibase
[WARN] com.test.myapp.admin.config.liquibase.AsyncSpringLiquibase - Starting Liquibase asynchronously, your database might not be ready at startup!
[DEBUG] com.test.myapp.admin.config.CacheConfiguration - No cache
[INFO] com.test.myapp.admin.Application - Running with Spring profile(s) : [dev]
[INFO] com.test.myapp.admin.config.ThymeleafConfiguration - loading non-reloadable mail messages resources
[DEBUG] com.test.myapp.admin.config.apidoc.SwaggerConfiguration - Starting Swagger
[DEBUG] com.test.myapp.admin.config.apidoc.SwaggerConfiguration - Started Swagger in 12 ms
[DEBUG] com.test.myapp.admin.aop.logging.LoggingAspect - Enter: com.test.myapp.admin.repository.CustomAuditEventRepository.auditEventRepository() with argument[s] = []
[DEBUG] com.test.myapp.admin.aop.logging.LoggingAspect - Exit: com.test.myapp.admin.repository.CustomAuditEventRepository.auditEventRepository() with result = com.test.myapp.admin.repository.CustomAuditEventRepository$1@6a073c63
[INFO] com.test.myapp.admin.Application - Started Application in 8.847 seconds (JVM running for 9.22)
[INFO] com.test.myapp.admin.Application - Access URLs:
----------------------------------------------------------
    Local:      http://127.0.0.1:8080
    External:   http://192.168.87.14:8080
----------------------------------------------------------
[DEBUG] com.test.myapp.admin.config.liquibase.AsyncSpringLiquibase - Started Liquibase in 5800 ms
> Building 87% > :bootRun
```

Answer (score 1):

I asked the Gradle folks about this last night. They said it's because Gradle calculates the percentage of tasks that have been run as part of the build. When "bootrun" executes, 87% of the tasks in the build have run.

Comment: Ok, but why does that line never go away?

Comment: Because the spring-boot plugin suspends the build, preventing Gradle from completing all 100% of the tasks.

Comment: Thanks for your time and patience on this as I try to grok jhipster.  Is it a problem that Gradle never completes all of the tasks?  How do I find out which tasks weren't completed?

Comment: I believe these are tasks like packaging and such, which doesn't need to occur when you're just running your application.

Comment: Is there a simple way to get rid of the "Building 87%" display? Would be nice to be able to run a command line app properly from the command line... O:)

Comment: I have the same issue when I run `gradle appengineRun`. I'm not sure if there is an issue or not. It says `87% EXECUTING`.